# Web Sql - Fazer select a partir de ID

Tags: javascript, websql

Estou tentando fazer um `select` a partir de um `ID` que será pego no `value` de um `option`, dei uma pesquisada na net e vi que colocam isso dentro de uma função, mas quando eu coloco a função, a variável que deveria armazenar o valor, simplesmente não funciona mais.

Dessa maneira que tá o código ela funciona e até chega a pegar o valor, mas ela não funciona no `select` do DB, tudo o que tentei fazer sempre algo deixa de funcionar.

```
    var myTest = document.getElementById("list").value;        
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM exercicios WHERE se_id = ?', [myTest],
            function(tx, results){
                var exlist = document.getElementById("exlist");

                for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = results.rows.item(i);
                    exlist.innerHTML += "<li>" + row.se_id + " - " + row.ex_nome + "</li>";
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

Comment: Meu amigo, cuidado com códigos de inputs misturados com queries sql e outputs de html... está na hora de buscar uma arquitetura. Estes código que "até funcionam" uma hora vão te dar muita dor de cabeça.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por um acaso seu `se_id` é numérico? Quando você faz:

```
var myTest = document.getElementById("list").value;
```

O valor de `myTest` é uma string. Usá-lo no `select` fará com que ele não retorne nenhum resultado se o `se_id` for numérico. Experimente transformar esse valor num inteiro antes de usar no `select`:

```
var myTest = parseInt(document.getElementById("list").value, 10);
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/EQXx6/).

Comment: Ainda não resolveu. Coloquei um exemplo no jsFiddle pra ver se facilita: http://jsfiddle.net/jb24d/

Comment: @AltembergAndrade Comigo funcionou - só tive que corrigir dois erros no seu fiddle: 1) coloquei a criação das tabelas num *callback* do `openDatabase` para ele não inserir novas linhas toda vez que o teste é executado; 2) Criei a função `listExs` que você não tinha criado e passei o código do select pra dentro dela. http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/jb24d/1/